# Invalid or missing required CSRF token when deploying metadata via Workbench

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

I am merging orgs and have the prepped all the package.xml files. I've also retrieved the metadata.

When I deploy to the target org, I get this error message:

403 Forbidden
Invalid or missing required CSRF token

Tried on different networks and I am System Administrator profile on both orgs.

Comment: If you try to deploy something really small (like one item), does it work?

Comment: Successful for one item.

Comment: Maybe this is something related to large size of zip